# Add ngOnChange handler to whole angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm an angular beginner, trying to replace text all over my UI which is an Angular project of which I only have parts of the code (un-uglified, I mean).

So, I'm looking for a trigger in the NgModule (my main App class) to iterate through all objects and replace the text.

Currently, I'm just totally lost in documentation, don't know where to look and where to start to add this.

```
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule as NgRouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UpgradeModule as NgUpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { CoreModule, HOOK_ACTION, RouterModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components';
import {
  DashboardUpgradeModule,
  UpgradeModule,
  HybridAppModule,
  UPGRADE_ROUTES
} from '@c8y/ngx-components/upgrade';
import { AssetsNavigatorModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/assets-navigator';
import { CockpitDashboardModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/context-dashboard';
import { ReportsModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/reports';
import { SensorPhoneModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/sensor-phone';
import { ProductExperienceModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/product-experience';
import { BinaryFileDownloadModule } from '@c8y/ngx-components/binary-file-download';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Upgrade module must be the first
    UpgradeModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(),
    NgRouterModule.forRoot([...UPGRADE_ROUTES], { enableTracing: false, useHash: true }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    AssetsNavigatorModule,
    ReportsModule,
    NgUpgradeModule,
    DashboardUpgradeModule,
    CockpitDashboardModule,
    SensorPhoneModule,
    ProductExperienceModule,
    BinaryFileDownloadModule
  ]
})



export class AppModule extends HybridAppModule implements OnInit{
  updateText(index, value){
    value.innerHTML = value.innerHTML.replace("Peter","Parker");
    console.log("Index:"+ index + "Value: "+value);
  }

  constructor(protected upgrade: NgUpgradeModule) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("Running Replacement Task");
    $('label').each((index, value) =>{this.updateText(index, value)});      
    $('span').each((index, value) =>{this.updateText(index, value)});      
    $('div').each((index, value) =>{this.updateText(index, value)});      
    $('text').each((index, value) =>{this.updateText(index, value)});        
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work (and please stay away from jQuery). Where is that data (‘Peter’) coming from anyway? Is the string you want to replace hardcoded in templates..? Does it come from API data..?

Comment: The strings are not hardcoded in template, they need to be translated when the view is updated. They are coming from an API